# Почему нажатие на 123 - редирект, на твит-кнопку - нет? Все в одном блоке.

Tags: jquery

Господа, почему, если нажать на 123 - есть редирект. А если на кнопку твитерскую - нету?

Но ведь и "123" и кнопка находятся внутри блока, для которого прописан редирект при клике.

Почему? Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку был также редирект, помимо остальных фишек?

http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon/780725675/index.php

Comment: а что не понятно, скорей всего по клику на твиттеровскую кнопку происходит return false и все дальнейшие манипуляции прекращаются

Comment: Ну та же хрень и с фэйсбуком и с вк. Можно это как-то обойти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видим:

```
        $('#twibtn').click(function(){
         go2Page(); 
         });
       $('#fbtn').click(function(){
         go2Page();

         });        
        $('#vkbtn').click(function(){
         go2Page();               
         }); 
        });
        function go2Page() {
        window.location.href = "http://likebox.ru/qr/cupon/860984434/cupon.php";
        return false;
        };
```

....

```
    <div id="tw" class="soc">
<img src="/qr/images/twi.png" /> <span><div id="twibtn">123<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/vsegdavkurse" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="ru" data-size="large">Читать в твиттере</a></span>
</div></div>
```

Из всего из этого следует, что для 123 у вас прописан обработчик, а для #tw - нет.
Пропишите, и будет вам счастье.

hint:

```
$(".soc#tw img").click(function(){
             go2Page(); 
             });
```

Comment: Это не решение проблемы. Это костыли. все, что внутри блока с id twibtn должно работать, верно? Ведь об этом говорит функция $('#twibtn').click(function() - почему работает только 123?

Таже штука и с фэйсбуком для виджетов и для вк.